# How to fit landscape multi-page table to textwidth

Tags: margins, longtable, landscape

```
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

% Table here

\end{longtable}%
}%
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

I am unable to get the table to span over multiple pages while fitting the table to the width of the landscape page.
Would you know how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Consider using the [`ltxtable` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable). As suggested by its slogan: "`ltxtable`: `longtable` meets `tabularx`"

Answer (score 18):

First off, don't use both `table` and `longtable` -- the two environments shouldn't (and mustn't) be nested. Separately, since a `longtable` isn't a float (in the LaTeX sense of the word), there's no point providing location directives such as `[!htb]`.

Second, to force the width of the `longtable` environment to be equal to `\textwidth`, type something like

```
\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{15}{c|}}
... % tabular material here
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
...
```

Note that the code above also resets the `\LTcapwidth` macro; since you're working in `landscape` mode, you'll almost certainly want to override this macro's default value of 4 inches. The `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive, by the way, is exactly the same as what one would use in a `tabular*` environment. It tells LaTeX to insert `\fill` -- an infinitely stretchable amount of whitespace -- in each intercolumn space.

For more information on using the `longtable` environment, see the longtable user guide; if you're using TeXLive or MikTeX, the user guide may be brought up by typing `texdoc longtable` in a command window.

Comment: `texdoc longtable`also works if you are using a MikTeX installation.

Comment: @Sveinung -- good point! I'll add this piece of information.

Comment: Which part of your code forces the width of the longtable environment to be equal to \textwidth?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - it's the resetting of the length parameters `\LTleft` and `\LTright`, along with the insertion of the directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` at the start of the `longtable` environment.

Comment: It still exceeds the page width here. I'm probably doing something wrong. I'm new to tex. I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - please go ahead and post a query with a minimum working example of the code that's giving you problems.