# longtable spanning textwidth

Tags: longtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fit landscape multi-page table to textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54302/how-to-fit-landscape-multi-page-table-to-textwidth)

I am trying to fit a `longtable` in a page with the following specifications:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.7cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|>{\raggedright}p{4.5in}|p{0.85in}|}
\hline
\textbf{Week} & \textbf{Content} & \textbf{Assessments}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\hline
\textbf{Week} & \textbf{Content} & \textbf{Assessments}\tabularnewline
\hline
\hline
\endhead
\hline
Week 1 & Unit 1
&HW, Q, T\tabularnewline
\hline
Week 2 & Unit 2
&HW, Q, T\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Note that to the naked eye, the table seems to be perfect, but I know that one can make the long table to span through the entire text width. I am looking for improvements and how to achieve the above effect (use of the text width.) If a similar question has been asked please redirect me.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is: longtable always uses the full text width by default. There is (as always with latex tables) a tabcolsep at either side which you could remove by putting `@{}` at the start an end of the column specification. Or is your question that you want the `p` column widths to be automatic, like `tabularx` `X` columns in which case you might look at `ltxtable` or perhaps `tabu`

Answer (score 14):

Page 7 of the user guide of the `longtable` package suggests issuing the commands

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
...
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}...} % replace "..." with actual column specifiers
```

to get a `longtable` that's automatically as wide as `\textwidth`. For the case of your table, you'd either issue the two `\setlength` commands in the preamble (to make them apply to *all* longtable environments) or localize them in a TeX group (so that they only apply to the `longtable`(s) within that group). Then, you'd use the command

```
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|>{\raggedright}p{4.5in}|p{0.85in}|}
```

to force this particular `longtable` to occupy the entire width of the text block.

**Addendum**: After posting this answer, I came across [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54396/5001) which deals, in essence, with the very same topic. I should have remembered this earlier, given that I was one of the persons who posted an answer...

Comment: If it is a duplicate, please close. :-)

Comment: `! Missing number, treated as zero.`.

Comment: @barej - Sorry, but my mind-reading skills are quite poor. Please tell me more about the code that's giving rise to the error message. For sure, the following compilable example does *not* generate any warning or error messages.  `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{longtable} \begin{document} \setlength\LTleft{0pt} \setlength\LTright{0pt} \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|>{\raggedright}p{3in}|p{1in}|} \hline a & b & c \\ \hline \end{longtable} \end{document} `,