# How to construct a table in IEEE format in latex that covers both the column and goes beyond a page?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

The Situation The code if executed could develop a table the covers the entire page in IEEE format but when I try to make the table more than a page longer, it doesn't show the last data of the code that goes beyond one page.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % filler text
\begin{table*}
 \caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{10}{C}c@{}}
\toprule
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer & dog & frog & horse & ship & truck & accuracy \\ 
\midrule
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[2-15] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

I want to find a way to include a table in IEEE format in Latex where it can cover the entire page instead of just half and goes beyond a single page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Would [longtable spanning textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61564/13304) and the related [How to fit landscape multi-page table to textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54302/13304) help?

Comment: Try nesting a `longtable` in a `strip` environment, defined un the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch to `\onecolumn`, use `longtable` then switch back to `\twocolumn`

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,longtable}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % filler text


\onecolumn
\begin{longtable}{@{}l*{11}{c}@{}}
\caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix\label{my-label}}\\
\toprule
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer & dog & frog & horse & ship & truck & accuracy \\ 
\midrule
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\twocolumn
\lipsum[2-15] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But the table width for my actual table was long so I used the same in landscape with \resizebox. Now I am looking for a way to put same headers on both pages.

Comment: @Bisu - Somewhat related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=3|15.0813#477197

Comment: never use \resizebox on tables it produces inconsitent fonts and rulesizes just use a smaller font such as `\small` if needed.  You can use longtable in landscape. @Bisu

Answer (score 2):

You can manually split your table into two, approximately equal parts and insert the first part at the bottom of a page, and the second part on the top of the page. At this for correct caption numbering had to be used `\ContinuedFloat` as defined in the `caption page.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[!b]
\caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{tab: mytable}
    \centering%
\begin{tabular}{l*{10}{S[table-format=3.0]} c }
     \toprule
labels      & {airplane}
                    & {automobile}
                            & {bird}
                                   & {cat}
                                         & {deer}
                                                & {dog}
                                                      & {frog}
                                                             & {horse}
                                                                     & {ship}
                                                                            & {truck}
                                                                                    & accuracy (\%)\\
    \midrule
airplane    & 915   & 4     & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2    & 27    & 12    & 91.50    \\
automobile  & 8     & 934   & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0    & 10    & 38    & 93.40    \\
bird        & 60    & 1     & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10   & 7     & 0     & 81.30    \\
cat         & 18    & 1     & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18   & 8     & 0     & 74.60    \\
deer        & 24    & 1     & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29   & 2     & 1     & 80.90    \\
    \addlinespace
dog         & 4     & 0     & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26   & 2     & 1     & 79.20    \\
frog        & 2     & 5     & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2    & 3     & 1     & 91.20    \\
horse       & 14    & 0     & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886  & 3     & 1     & 88.60    \\
ship        & 35    & 10    & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0    & 936   & 11    & 93.60    \\
truck       & 23    & 37    & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0    & 15    & 906   & 90.60    \\
airplane    & 915   & 4     & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2    & 27    & 12    & 91.50    \\
automobile  & 8     & 934   & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0    & 10    & 38    & 93.40    \\
bird        & 60    & 1     & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10   & 7     & 0     & 81.30    \\
cat         & 18    & 1     & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18   & 8     & 0     & 74.60    \\
deer        & 24    & 1     & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29   & 2     & 1     & 80.90    \\
    \addlinespace
dog         & 4     & 0     & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26   & 2     & 1     & 79.20    \\
frog        & 2     & 5     & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2    & 3     & 1     & 91.20    \\
horse       & 14    & 0     & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886  & 3     & 1     & 88.60    \\
ship        & 35    & 10    & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0    & 936   & 11    & 93.60    \\
truck       & 23    & 37    & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0    & 15    & 906   & 90.60    \\
airplane    & 915   & 4     & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2    & 27    & 12    & 91.50    \\
automobile  & 8     & 934   & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0    & 10    & 38    & 93.40    \\
bird        & 60    & 1     & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10   & 7     & 0     & 81.30    \\
cat         & 18    & 1     & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18   & 8     & 0     & 74.60    \\
deer        & 24    & 1     & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29   & 2     & 1     & 80.90    \\
    \addlinespace
dog         & 4     & 0     & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26   & 2     & 1     & 79.20    \\
frog        & 2     & 5     & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2    & 3     & 1     & 91.20    \\
horse       & 14    & 0     & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886  & 3     & 1     & 88.60    \\
ship        & 35    & 10    & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0    & 936   & 11    & 93.60    \\
truck       & 23    & 37    & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0    & 15    & 906   & 90.60    \\
airplane    & 915   & 4     & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2    & 27    & 12    & 91.50    \\
automobile  & 8     & 934   & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0    & 10    & 38    & 93.40    \\
bird        & 60    & 1     & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10   & 7     & 0     & 81.30    \\
cat         & 18    & 1     & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18   & 8     & 0     & 74.60    \\
deer        & 24    & 1     & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29   & 2     & 1     & 80.90    \\
    \addlinespace
dog         & 4     & 0     & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26   & 2     & 1     & 79.20    \\
frog        & 2     & 5     & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2    & 3     & 1     & 91.20    \\
horse       & 14    & 0     & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886  & 3     & 1     & 88.60    \\
ship        & 35    & 10    & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0    & 936   & 11    & 93.60    \\
truck       & 23    & 37    & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0    & 15    & 906   & 90.60    \\
airplane    & 915   & 4     & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2    & 27    & 12    & 91.50    \\
automobile  & 8     & 934   & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0    & 10    & 38    & 93.40    \\
bird        & 60    & 1     & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10   & 7     & 0     & 81.30    \\
cat         & 18    & 1     & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18   & 8     & 0     & 74.60    \\
deer        & 24    & 1     & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29   & 2     & 1     & 80.90    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
%
    \begin{table*}[!t]
    \ContinuedFloat
\caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{tab: mytable}
    \centering%
\begin{tabular}{l*{10}{S[table-format=3.0]} c}
     \toprule
labels      & {airplane}
                    & {automobile}
                            & {bird}
                                   & {cat}
                                         & {deer}
                                                & {dog}
                                                      & {frog}
                                                             & {horse}
                                                                     & {ship}
                                                                            & {truck}
                                                                                    & accuracy (\%)\\
    \midrule
dog         & 4     & 0     & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26   & 2    & 1   & 79.20    \\
frog        & 2     & 5     & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2    & 3    & 1   & 91.20    \\
horse       & 14    & 0     & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886  & 3    & 1   & 88.60    \\
ship        & 35    & 10    & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0    & 936  & 11  & 93.60    \\
truck       & 23    & 37    & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0    & 15   & 906 & 90.60    \\
airplane    & 915   & 4     & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2    & 27   & 12  & 91.50    \\
automobile  & 8     & 934   & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0    & 10   & 38  & 93.40    \\
bird        & 60    & 1     & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10   & 7    & 0   & 81.30    \\
cat         & 18    & 1     & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18   & 8    & 0   & 74.60    \\
deer        & 24    & 1     & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29   & 2    & 1   & 80.90    \\
    \addlinespace
dog         & 4     & 0     & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26   & 2    & 1   & 79.20    \\
frog        & 2     & 5     & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2    & 3    & 1   & 91.20    \\
horse       & 14    & 0     & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886  & 3    & 1   & 88.60    \\
ship        & 35    & 10    & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0    & 936  & 11  & 93.60    \\
truck       & 23    & 37    & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0    & 15   & 906 & 90.60    \\
airplane    & 915   & 4     & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2    & 27   & 12  & 91.50    \\
automobile  & 8     & 934   & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0    & 10   & 38  & 93.40    \\
bird        & 60    & 1     & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10   & 7    & 0   & 81.30    \\
cat         & 18    & 1     & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18   & 8    & 0   & 74.60    \\
deer        & 24    & 1     & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29   & 2    & 1   & 80.90    \\
    \addlinespace
dog         & 4     & 0     & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26   & 2    & 1   & 79.20    \\
frog        & 2     & 5     & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2    & 3    & 1   & 91.20    \\
horse       & 14    & 0     & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886  & 3    & 1   & 88.60    \\
ship        & 35    & 10    & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0    & 936  & 11  & 93.60    \\
truck       & 23    & 37    & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0    & 15   & 906 & 90.60    \\
airplane    & 915   & 4     & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2    & 27   & 12  & 91.50    \\
automobile  & 8     & 934   & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0    & 10   & 38  & 93.40    \\
bird        & 60    & 1     & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10   & 7    & 0   & 81.30    \\
cat         & 18    & 1     & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18   & 8    & 0   & 74.60    \\
deer        & 24    & 1     & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29   & 2    & 1   & 80.90    \\
    \addlinespace
dog         & 4     & 0     & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26   & 2    & 1   & 79.20    \\
frog        & 2     & 5     & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2    & 3    & 1   & 91.20    \\
horse       & 14    & 0     & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886  & 3    & 1   & 88.60    \\
ship        & 35    & 10    & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0    & 936  & 11  & 93.60    \\
truck       & 23    & 37    & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0    & 15   & 906 & 90.60    \\
airplane    & 915   & 4     & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2    & 27   & 12  & 91.50    \\
automobile  & 8     & 934   & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0    & 10   & 38  & 93.40    \\
bird        & 60    & 1     & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10   & 7    & 0   & 81.30    \\
cat         & 18    & 1     & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18   & 8    & 0   & 74.60    \\
deer        & 24    & 1     & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29   & 2    & 1   & 80.90    \\
    \addlinespace
dog         & 4     & 0     & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26   & 2    & 1   & 79.20    \\
frog        & 2     & 5     & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2    & 3    & 1   & 91.20    \\
horse       & 14    & 0     & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886  & 3    & 1   & 88.60    \\
ship        & 35    & 10    & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0    & 936  & 11  & 93.60    \\
truck       & 23    & 37    & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0    & 15   & 906 & 90.60    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

The second possibilities is to schrink table width to `\columnwidth`. This can be achieved by the following changes in above MWE:

- reduce font size to `\footnotesize`
- reduce distance between columns to `3pt`
- rotate column headers

Simple table code with above changes offer `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}   % needed
\usepackage{makecell}   % needed
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!b]
\caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{tab: mytable}
    \centering 
    \footnotesize 
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{automobile}% from makecell
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{\!} l*{10}{Q[c,si={table-format=3.0}]}c @{\!}},
             colsep = {3pt},
             rowsep = 1pt,
             cell{1}{2-Z}={cmd=\rotcell, font=\footnotesize}, % <----
             }
     \toprule
\SetCell[c=1]{f}  labels
            & {{{airplane}}}
                    & {{{automobile}}}
                            & {{{bird}}}
                                   & {{{cat}}}
                                         & {{{deer}}}
                                                & {{{dog}}}
                                                      & {{{frog}}}
                                                             & {{{horse}}}
                                                                    & {{{ship}}}
                                                                            & {{{truck}}}
                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{accuracy}\\
    \midrule
% rest of the first part of table body is the same as at the first example
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
%
    \begin{table}[!t]
    \ContinuedFloat
\caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{tab: mytable}
    \centering%
    \footnotesize%
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{automobile}% from makecell
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{\!} l*{10}{Q[c,si={table-format=3.0}]}c @{\!}},
             colsep = {3pt},
             rowsep = 1pt,
             cell{1}{2-Z}={l,cmd=\rotcell, font=\footnotesize}, % <----
             }
     \toprule
\SetCell[c=1]{f}  labels
            & {{{airplane}}}
                    & {{{automobile}}}
                            & {{{bird}}}
                                   & {{{cat}}}
                                         & {{{deer}}}
                                                & {{{dog}}}
                                                      & {{{frog}}}
                                                             & {{{horse}}}
                                                                    & {{{ship}}}
                                                                           & {{{truck}}}
                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{accuracy}\\
    \midrule
% rest of the second part of table body is the same as at the first example
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should omit `\begin{table*} ... \end{table*}` and use [`longtable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable?lang=en) package. To avoid warning from `longtable` package, use this lines before and after `longtable` command.

```
\clearpage
\onecolumn
\begin{longtable}
...
\end{longtable}
\clearpage
\twocolumn
```

Hope you understand.
I have prepare my MWE for you:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % filler text
\clearpage
\onecolumn
%\begin{table*}
\begin{longtable}{l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l}
\caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{my-label} \\
\hline
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer & dog & frog & horse & ship & truck & accuracy \\ \hline

airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
%\end{table*}
\clearpage
\twocolumn
\lipsum[2-15] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just of curiosity: Why do you recommend not using `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc?