# LaTeX split long table in multiple pages and resize the width

Tags: tables, longtable, lengths, width

I am trying to find a way to fix the width of my table to the margin of a portrait page (not landscape) while continuing the table in another page since it is very long. I can adjust the width by using resizebox (I found this better than adjustbox because I wanted to keep the caption and labels of the table as it is in other smaller tables I have), but I don't know how to continue in to another page. Using just the code below cuts the rest of the table in length since my table is also long. I am looking for a way to fit the width of the table automatically, but also have the table continue in a different page (for example using 'longtable' with resizebox?). 
My question is similar to this one 
[Resize longtable to width of landscape page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54396/resize-longtable-to-width-of-landscape-page) 
 but I do not want a landscape.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\small  % Switch from 12pt to 11pt; otherwise, table won't fit
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
\begin{longtable}{llllllllll}
  \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
   category & level & type & num1 & num2 & num3 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$S1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$S2$} \\ [0.5ex] 
    \hline % inserts single horizontal line
 &  &  &  &  &  & PP3 & PP4 & PP3 & PP4 \\
E1 & 7E-54 & S2 & NA & NA & NA & NA & NA & NA & NA \\
E2 & 4E-8 & S1 & 1 & 25428038:25828097 & 10023824146 & 9 & 91 & 50 & 50 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25456834:25856893 & 10025905748 & 0.129 & 2.26 & 0.133 & 0.23 \\
&  & S & 1 & 25428038:25828097 & 10023824146 & 8.9 & 91.1 & 49.7 & 50.3 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25456834:25856893 & 10025905748 & 0.129 & 2.22 & 0.133 & 0.226 \\
E3 & 4E-8 & S2 & 1 & 25488669:25888728 & 10025910500 & 12 & 88 & 57.7 & 42.2 \\
 &  & S & 1 & 25488669:25888728 & 10025910500 & 13.2 & 86.8 & 60.5 & 39.5 \\
E4 & 2E-145 & S1 & 1 & 25626305:26026364 & 10023820955 & 1.04 & 99 & 10.3 & 89.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25624780:26024839 & 10025907287 & 1.92 & 98 & 16.9 & 82.5 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25625807:26025866 & 10025935784 & 2.45 & 97.5 & 20.7 & 79.3 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 25626305:26026364 & 10023820955 & 1.09 & 98.9 & 10.6 & 89.4 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25624780:26024839 & 10025907287 & 1.92 & 98 & 16.9 & 82.5 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25625807:26025866 & 10025935784 & 3.29 & 96.7 & 25.9 & 74.1 \\
E5 & 1E-13 & S2 & 1 & 62870388:63270447 & 10023831002 & 9.39 & 90.6 & 51.1 & 48.9 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62870388:63270447 & 10023831002 & 9.47 & 90.5 & 51.3 & 48.7 \\
 &  & S4 & 1 & 62870388:63270447 & 10023831002 & 7.64 & 92.4 & 45.5 & 54.5 \\
E6 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E7 & 5E-94 & S1 & 1 & 109618271:110018330 & 10025913212 & 0.159 & 99.8 & 2.43 & 97.6 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 109618271:110018330 & 10025913212 & 0.189 & 99.8 & 2.72 & 97.3 \\
E8 & 9.00E-17 & S1 & 1 & 109744528:110144587 & 10025910902 & 0.702 & 99.3 & 7.38 & 92.6 \\
E8 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E9 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E10 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E11 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E12 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E13 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E14 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E15 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
      \begin{flushleft}This is the captio of my table
     \end{flushleft}
      \label{tab:label}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you reference (and the one that it references as duplicate) the only part of that code related to landscape is `\begin{landscape}` `\end{landscape}` so just omit those lines.

Comment: resizing tables with `\resizebox` (even when single page) is a bad idea as it leads to arbitrary, inconsistent font sizes. Better to choose a suitable font size (eg `\small` and then format the column widths to fit)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your help. Just taking out the \begin{landscape} \end{landscape} and copying the code in the question I referred to does not work, the length still gets cut off and the table is interrupted wihtuot finishing…

Comment: In that case there is an error in your code but since you haven't shown any code it's hard to help. Please make a complete small document (you can reduce `\textheight` so you only need a few rows) that shows the problem and edit your question to include it. Code in questions should _always_ have `\documentclass....\end{document}` so people can run the example and see the problem.

Comment: Sorry Claudio and David for the bad example, I now posted a reproducible example.

Comment: The table interrupts at E11 and cannot see anything more… Why is this happening while using longtable? thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As documented a `table` is a box so can not break over a page `longtable` should not be used with it. Removing that fixes most of the problems, then just change the size and squeeze the columns a bit and it all fits.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}



\footnotesize  % Switch from 12pt to 11pt; otherwise, table won't fit
\setlength\LTleft{-30pt}            % default: \fill
\setlength\LTright{-30pt}           % default: \fill
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llllllllll@{}}
  \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
   cat. & level & type & num1 & num2 & num3 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$S1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$S2$} \\ [0.5ex] 
    \hline % inserts single horizontal line
 &  &  &  &  &  & PP3 & PP4 & PP3 & PP4 \\
E1 & 7E-54 & S2 & NA & NA & NA & NA & NA & NA & NA \\
E2 & 4E-8 & S1 & 1 & 25428038:25828097 & 10023824146 & 9 & 91 & 50 & 50 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25456834:25856893 & 10025905748 & 0.129 & 2.26 & 0.133 & 0.23 \\
&  & S & 1 & 25428038:25828097 & 10023824146 & 8.9 & 91.1 & 49.7 & 50.3 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25456834:25856893 & 10025905748 & 0.129 & 2.22 & 0.133 & 0.226 \\
E3 & 4E-8 & S2 & 1 & 25488669:25888728 & 10025910500 & 12 & 88 & 57.7 & 42.2 \\
 &  & S & 1 & 25488669:25888728 & 10025910500 & 13.2 & 86.8 & 60.5 & 39.5 \\
E4 & 2E-145 & S1 & 1 & 25626305:26026364 & 10023820955 & 1.04 & 99 & 10.3 & 89.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25624780:26024839 & 10025907287 & 1.92 & 98 & 16.9 & 82.5 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25625807:26025866 & 10025935784 & 2.45 & 97.5 & 20.7 & 79.3 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 25626305:26026364 & 10023820955 & 1.09 & 98.9 & 10.6 & 89.4 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25624780:26024839 & 10025907287 & 1.92 & 98 & 16.9 & 82.5 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 25625807:26025866 & 10025935784 & 3.29 & 96.7 & 25.9 & 74.1 \\
E5 & 1E-13 & S2 & 1 & 62870388:63270447 & 10023831002 & 9.39 & 90.6 & 51.1 & 48.9 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62870388:63270447 & 10023831002 & 9.47 & 90.5 & 51.3 & 48.7 \\
 &  & S4 & 1 & 62870388:63270447 & 10023831002 & 7.64 & 92.4 & 45.5 & 54.5 \\
E6 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E7 & 5E-94 & S1 & 1 & 109618271:110018330 & 10025913212 & 0.159 & 99.8 & 2.43 & 97.6 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 109618271:110018330 & 10025913212 & 0.189 & 99.8 & 2.72 & 97.3 \\
E8 & 9.00E-17 & S1 & 1 & 109744528:110144587 & 10025910902 & 0.702 & 99.3 & 7.38 & 92.6 \\
E8 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E9 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E10 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E11 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E12 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E13 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E14 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
E15 & 1E-22 & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.44 & 94.6 & 36.9 & 63.1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.5 & 1.79 & 1.54 \\
 &  & S3 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 4.63 & 95.4 & 33.1 & 66.9 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.56 & 13.8 & 1.79 & 1.58 \\
 &  & S2 & 1 & 62849818:63249877 & 10023825945 & 5.54 & 94.5 & 37.3 & 62.7 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 62720869:63120928 & 10023851197 & 1.55 & 14.3 & 1.79 & 1.64 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David. I had tried specifying the -28points for the limits of the table page but then the borders of the table using \hline and the \begin{flushleft} for the caption does not enclose all of the table… Is there a way t specify that the borders and caption should follow these limits too? Thanks again

Comment: @user971102 ah maybe you should take them out and then use -ve spacing for the \LTleft and \LTright then \hline will work, It is best to put your caption inside the longtable so it repeats on later pages, see the longtable documentation.

Comment: Ah thank you! this way the hline is enclosing the whole table. The caption is still not following the limits specified though even when using it inside longtable.. For example using \caption{These are the results of density levels in different concentrations and different environments for one of the samples} it seems to print it all within a small area… I guess I am not understanding how to specify these lengths for the whole {longtable} if there is a way...

Comment: @user971102 LTcaptions are set to \LTcapwidth so you'll need to set that to 60pt more than textwidth

Comment: Thank you David. Before beginning the longtable I added this \advance\LTcapwidth by 360pt 
And it worked… I was hoping it would just adjust everything within the \begin{longtable} and \end{longtable} automatically but I was wrong, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was using the multi-pages table option in Lyx 2.2, but it simply didn't work at all. I just moved the table outside of my figure float box, and then it worked perfectly well!