# Longtable set to textwidth

Tags: longtable

I have to vera long tables underneath eatchother. Both don't fill up the whole text width, the second even less so. I have no idea why they do that since all other tables made with `longtable` automatically took up the same width as the text. I've read the documentation on the longtable package but have no idea what to put instead of the dots in `\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{...}}...}`. Do I have to calculate something?

Comment: Have you compiled twice?

Comment: Yes, several times. I've had this problem for more than a week now.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54304/9632

Comment: Try \extracolsep{\fill}

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can load the `ltablex` package and use a `tabularx{\linewidth}` environment: it brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`.