# How to make longtable width to textwidth?

Tags: longtable, textwidth

I am trying to center a side longtable using `\makebox[\textwidth]{` it worked for a normal table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \begin{longtable}
        {>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.55\textwidth} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.55\textwidth}}
        \lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \
  \end{longtable}
}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

I use sharelatex and get the error `Missing \endgroup inserted.`.

edit: I saw [How to fit landscape multi-page table to textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54302/how-to-fit-landscape-multi-page-table-to-textwidth) but `LTcapwidth` didn't help

Comment: as you see this  does not work at all for longtable, but it is not a good way to center a tabular either, better to use `\centering` (longtables are by default, so there is nothing to do in that case)

Comment: your title asks about making a table full width but the text of your question asks about centreing,  which do you want to do?  If something is full width then centering is a no-op, longtables are centred by default, the posted answers show how to make it full width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`longtable` has its own method for this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begingroup % localize the following settings
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt minus 1000pt}
\setlength{\LTright}{0pt minus 1000pt}

\begin{longtable}{
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.55\textwidth}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.55\textwidth}
}
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3]
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `xltabular` instead of `longtable`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begingroup % localize the following settings
\setlength\LTleft{0pt minus 1000pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt minus 1000pt}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{xltabular}{1.1\linewidth}{>{\centering}X>{\centering}X}
        \lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3]
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]