# fit longtable to textwidth

Tags: tables, longtable, fit, resize, textwidth

I am applying [How to fit landscape multi-page table to textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54302/how-to-fit-landscape-multi-page-table-to-textwidth?answertab=active#tab-top) to fit longtable to textwidth in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{                                                                                                                                                                               
\begingroup % localize the following settings                                                                                                                                                               
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)                                                                                                                           
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent                                                                                                                                                     
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill                                                                                                                                                          
  \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|rcc|rcc|rcc|rcc|}
longtable aaaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaaa & 11.11 & 2 & 0.000 & 22.22 & 2 & 0.000 & 333.33 & 2 & 0.137 & 44.44 & 2 & 0.000\\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
%}
\end{document}
```

However, the outcome shows I haven't been successful:

[image]

What is wrong?

I check the answer of @DavidCarlisle. However, the proposed manipulations cause a problem with `\cline`:

```
\begingroup % localize the following settings                                                                                                                                                               
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)                                                                                                                           
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \parindent                                                                                                                                                     
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill                                                                                                                                                          
\tiny
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4pt}
                \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|p{3cm}|rcc|rcc|rcc|rcc|}
 Sample&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{AAAA}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{BBBB}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{CCCC}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{DDDDD}\\\cline{2-13}
                        lllllllllongtable & 11.11 & 2 & 0.000 & 22.22 & 2 & 0.000 & 33.33 & 2 & 00.00 & 44.44 & 2 & 0.000\\
                \end{longtable}
  \endgroup
```

[image]

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: as in `tabular*`, `\extracolsep{\fill}}` allows the table to _expand_ to the specified width, your table is too wide, so you need to use a multi-line cell (change the first  `l` to `p{2cm}` or whetever width you want) or use a smaller font such as `\small`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is there any analogue of `\resizebox`? It works so nice.

Comment: Should this table  be in landscape orientation?

Comment: @Bernard, my question is about portrait orientation

Comment: @Viesturs: I would definitely recommend to not use `resizebox` on material that contains text as it will lead to inconsistent font sized and distances.

Comment: `\resizebox` should never be used for tables, as it makes the font size inconsistent. B.t. w., do you use marginal notes?

Comment: You could make the table fit the fit into the textwidth using a combination of the `\small` font size, `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}` to reduce the horizontal whie space between columns and a `p{1.5cm}` column for the first column.

Comment: @Viesturs every time I see someone apply `\resizebox` to a table, I wish I'd never implemented it. You wouldn't justify a paragraph by just scaling it to an arbitrary font size, why inflict that in tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ never scale tables!                                                                                                                                                                              
\begingroup % localize the following settings                                                                    
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\footnotesize

\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)      

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \fill
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill                                                                                                    


  \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|p{2cm}|rcc|rcc|rcc|rcc|@{}}
longtable aaaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaaa & 11.11 & 2 & 0.000 & 22.22 & 2 & 0.000 & 333.33 & 2 & 0.137 & 44.44 & 2 & 0.000\\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
%}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution is causing a problem with `cline`. See the update of my question.

Comment: if you use `\extracolsep` then the space is inserted between columns and has the effect on cline that you show, so that is by design (personally I would not use `\extracolsep` forcing the columns apart doesn't make the tables more readable

Answer (score 4):

A solution with the `xltabular` package and its eponymous environment, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. I loaded the `geometry` package, to have more decent margins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begingroup % localize the following settings
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt} % default: \fill

  \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|rcc|rcc|rcc|rcc|}
longtable aaaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaaa & 11.11 & 2 & 0.000 & 22.22 & 2 & 0.000 & 333.33 & 2 & 0.137 & 44.44 & 2 & 0.000\\
\end{xltabular}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to centre vertically the cells with numerical values?

Comment: Redefine the `X` column  type as `m{#1}`, as was already answered to another of your questions, if I remember well.