# Make a big table fit exactly into two columns and not overflow

Tags: tables

My table is a little bit overflowing over the two columns of my paper towards the right, however I noticed that the cells of my table contain some space. Is there a way to minimize the spaces within the cells in order to stop my table from overflowing?

I would like to keep the table as it is and just minimize the space to make fit within the two columns of the paper.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\newcommand{\var}{\textit}
\newcommand{\proc}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\prop}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\plusplus}{{+}{+}}% Other options:
\newcommand*\ita[1]{\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}% new
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}
\begin{table*}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Precision/Recall and Completeness of the requirement-to-method
Traces Output by our approach}
\label{Results}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1-\\ Program\end{tabular}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2-\\ Step\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative\\ Predictions\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative \\ Output\\ Completeness\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative Precision and \\ Recall\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative \\ Output \\ Precision\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative\\  Output \\ Recall\end{tabular}}} \\ \cline{3-17}
    &  & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3-\\ T\textsubscript{p}(\#)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4-\\ N\textsubscript{p}(\#)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}5-\\ E\textsubscript{p}(\#)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}6-\\ T(\%)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}7-\\ N(\%)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}8-\\ E(\%)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}9-\\ TP\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}10-\\ TN\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}11-\\ FP\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}12-\\ FN\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}13-\\ E\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}14-\\ T(\%)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}15-\\ N(\%)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}16-\\ T(\%)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}17-\\ N(\%)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Chess}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 2063 & 3953 & 0 & 34.29 & 65.71 & 0 & 1612 & 0 & 0 & 4404 & NA & 100 & NA & 100 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{2} & 0 & 3227 & 2789 & 0 & 53.64 & 46.36 & 0 & 1841 & 0 & 49 & 4126 & NA & 97.41 & 0 & 100 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{3} & 908 & 3227 & 1881 & 15.09 & 53.64 & 31.27 & 415 & 1841 & 378 & 49 & 3333 & 52.33 & 97.41 & 89.44 & 82.97 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1464} & \textbf{3227} & \textbf{1325} & \textbf{24.34} & \textbf{53.64} & \textbf{22.02} & \textbf{471} & \textbf{1841} & \textbf{438} & \textbf{49} & \textbf{3217} & \textbf{51.82} & \textbf{97.41} & \textbf{90.58} & \textbf{80.78} \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Gantt}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 55535 & 34699 & 0 & 61.55 & 38.45 & 0 & 22365 & 0 & 0 & 67869 & NA & 100 & NA & 100 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{2} & 0 & 69880 & 20354 & 0 & 77.44 & 22.56 & 0 & 22707 & 0 & 94 & 67433 & NA & 99.59 & 0 & 100 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{3} & 677 & 69880 & 19677 & 0.75 & 77.44 & 21.81 & 84 & 22707 & 85 & 94 & 67264 & 49.70 & 99.59 & 47.19 & 99.63 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1143} & \textbf{69880} & \textbf{19211} & \textbf{1.27} & \textbf{77.44} & \textbf{21.29} & \textbf{136} & \textbf{22707} & \textbf{136} & \textbf{94} & \textbf{67161} & \textbf{50.00} & \textbf{99.59} & \textbf{59.13} & \textbf{99.40} \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{iTrust}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 17573 & 149265 & 0 & 10.53 & 89.47 & 0 & 6572 & 0 & 0 & 160266 & NA & 100 & NA & 100 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{2} & 0 & 28660 & 138178 & 0 & 17.18 & 82.82 & 0 & 6685 & 0 & 9 & 160144 & NA & 99.87 & 0 & 100 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{3} & 290 & 28660 & 137888 & 0.17 & 17.18 & 82.65 & 81 & 6685 & 27 & 9 & 160036 & 75.00 & 99.87 & 90.00 & 99.60 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1074} & \textbf{28660} & \textbf{137104} & \textbf{0.64} & \textbf{17.18} & \textbf{82.18} & \textbf{93} & \textbf{6685} & \textbf{28} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{160023} & \textbf{76.86} & \textbf{99.87} & \textbf{91.18} & \textbf{99.58} \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{JHotDraw}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 116787 & 20133 & 0 & 85.30 & 14.70 & 0 & 12013 & 0 & 0 & 124907 & NA & 100 & NA & 100 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{2} & 0 & 128756 & 8164 & 0 & 94.04 & 5.96 & 0 & 12134 & 0 & 208 & 124578 & NA & 98.31 & 0 & 100 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{3} & 1279 & 128756 & 6885 & 0.93 & 94.04 & 5.03 & 63 & 12134 & 20 & 208 & 124495 & 75.90 & 98.31 & 23.25 & 99.84 \\ \cline{2-17}
    & \textbf{4} & \textbf{2000} & \textbf{128756} & \textbf{6164} & \textbf{1.46} & \textbf{94.04} & \textbf{4.50} & \textbf{95} & \textbf{12134} & \textbf{32} & \textbf{208} & \textbf{124451} & \textbf{74.80} & \textbf{98.31} & \textbf{31.35} & \textbf{99.74} \\ \hline

%    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\textbf{Average} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1420} & \textbf{57631} & \textbf{40951} & \textbf{6.93} & \textbf{60.57} & \textbf{32.50} & \textbf{199} & \textbf{10842} & \textbf{159} & \textbf{90} & \textbf{88713} & \textbf{63.37} & \textbf{98.79} & \textbf{68.06} & \textbf{94.88} \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{...`

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,table]{IEEEtran} 
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\newcommand{\var}{\textit}
\newcommand{\proc}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\prop}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\plusplus}{{+}{+}}% Other options: 
\newcommand*\ita[1]{\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}% new
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\begin{table*}[htb]
\caption{Precision/Recall and Completeness of the requirement-to-method Traces Output 
by our approach}
\label{Results}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1-\\ Program\end{tabular}}} 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2-\\ Step\end{tabular}}} 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative\\ 
        Predictions\end{tabular}}} & 
        \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative \\ Output\\ 
        Completeness\end{tabular}}} & 
        \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative Precision 
        and \\ Recall\end{tabular}}} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative \\ Output \\ 
        Precision\end{tabular}}} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative\\  Output \\ 
        Recall\end{tabular}}} \\ \cline{3-17} 
        &  & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3-\\ 
        T\textsubscript{p}(\#)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4-\\ 
        N\textsubscript{p}(\#)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}5-\\ 
        E\textsubscript{p}(\#)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}6-\\ 
        T(\%)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}7-\\ 
        N(\%)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}8-\\ 
        E(\%)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}9-\\ TP\end{tabular}} 
        & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}10-\\ TN\end{tabular}} & 
        \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}11-\\ FP\end{tabular}} & 
        \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}12-\\ FN\end{tabular}} & 
        \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}13-\\ E\end{tabular}} & 
        \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}14-\\ T(\%)\end{tabular}} & 
        \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}15-\\ N(\%)\end{tabular}} & 
        \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}16-\\ T(\%)\end{tabular}} & 
        \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}17-\\ N(\%)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Chess}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 2063 & 3953 & 0 & 34.29 & 
        65.71 & 0 & 1612 & 0 & 0 & 4404 & NA & 100 & NA & 100 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{2} & 0 & 3227 & 2789 & 0 & 53.64 & 46.36 & 0 & 1841 & 0 & 49 & 4126 
        & NA & 97.41 & 0 & 100 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{3} & 908 & 3227 & 1881 & 15.09 & 53.64 & 31.27 & 415 & 1841 & 378 & 
        49 & 3333 & 52.33 & 97.41 & 89.44 & 82.97 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1464} & \textbf{3227} & \textbf{1325} & \textbf{24.34} 
        & \textbf{53.64} & \textbf{22.02} & \textbf{471} & \textbf{1841} & 
        \textbf{438} & \textbf{49} & \textbf{3217} & \textbf{51.82} & \textbf{97.41} & 
        \textbf{90.58} & \textbf{80.78} \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Gantt}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 55535 & 34699 & 0 & 61.55 & 
        38.45 & 0 & 22365 & 0 & 0 & 67869 & NA & 100 & NA & 100 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{2} & 0 & 69880 & 20354 & 0 & 77.44 & 22.56 & 0 & 22707 & 0 & 94 & 
        67433 & NA & 99.59 & 0 & 100 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{3} & 677 & 69880 & 19677 & 0.75 & 77.44 & 21.81 & 84 & 22707 & 85 & 
        94 & 67264 & 49.70 & 99.59 & 47.19 & 99.63 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1143} & \textbf{69880} & \textbf{19211} & \textbf{1.27} 
        & \textbf{77.44} & \textbf{21.29} & \textbf{136} & \textbf{22707} & 
        \textbf{136} & \textbf{94} & \textbf{67161} & \textbf{50.00} & \textbf{99.59} 
        & \textbf{59.13} & \textbf{99.40} \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{iTrust}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 17573 & 149265 & 0 & 10.53 
        & 89.47 & 0 & 6572 & 0 & 0 & 160266 & NA & 100 & NA & 100 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{2} & 0 & 28660 & 138178 & 0 & 17.18 & 82.82 & 0 & 6685 & 0 & 9 & 
        160144 & NA & 99.87 & 0 & 100 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{3} & 290 & 28660 & 137888 & 0.17 & 17.18 & 82.65 & 81 & 6685 & 27 & 
        9 & 160036 & 75.00 & 99.87 & 90.00 & 99.60 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1074} & \textbf{28660} & \textbf{137104} & 
        \textbf{0.64} & \textbf{17.18} & \textbf{82.18} & \textbf{93} & \textbf{6685} 
        & \textbf{28} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{160023} & \textbf{76.86} & \textbf{99.87} 
        & \textbf{91.18} & \textbf{99.58} \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{JHotDraw}} & \textbf{1} & 0 & 116787 & 20133 & 0 & 
        85.30 & 14.70 & 0 & 12013 & 0 & 0 & 124907 & NA & 100 & NA & 100 \\ 
        \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{2} & 0 & 128756 & 8164 & 0 & 94.04 & 5.96 & 0 & 12134 & 0 & 208 & 
        124578 & NA & 98.31 & 0 & 100 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{3} & 1279 & 128756 & 6885 & 0.93 & 94.04 & 5.03 & 63 & 12134 & 20 & 
        208 & 124495 & 75.90 & 98.31 & 23.25 & 99.84 \\ \cline{2-17} 
        & \textbf{4} & \textbf{2000} & \textbf{128756} & \textbf{6164} & \textbf{1.46} 
        & \textbf{94.04} & \textbf{4.50} & \textbf{95} & \textbf{12134} & \textbf{32} 
        & \textbf{208} & \textbf{124451} & \textbf{74.80} & \textbf{98.31} & 
        \textbf{31.35} & \textbf{99.74} \\ \hline

        %   \rowcolor{lightgray}
        \textbf{Average} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{1420} & \textbf{57631} & 
        \textbf{40951} & \textbf{6.93} & \textbf{60.57} & \textbf{32.50} & 
        \textbf{199} & \textbf{10842} & \textbf{159} & \textbf{90} & \textbf{88713} & 
        \textbf{63.37} & \textbf{98.79} & \textbf{68.06} & \textbf{94.88} \\ 
        \hline      
    \end{tabular}%
}
\end{table*}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't ever recommend using `\resizebox` to make tables "fit".

Comment: it depends always to the context where it will be used! So you are wrong with a _simple_ "don't use ..."

Comment: Answers provided on this site frequently end up getting used as templates by future readers, e.g., those looking for solutions for their too-wide tables. Since your answer provides *no context* -- such as a warning that `\resizebox` should only ever be contemplated in an emergency, *if all other measures have failed* -- it is entirely fair to call it out.

Comment: Since you provide *no context* for why this particular answer may be ok for the particular table at hand, it will quite likely mislead future readers of this posting into concluding that `\resizebox{\textwidth}{...}` is a panacea. A nuanced discussion of the circumstances under which `\resizebox` *may* be ok -- although other, superior solutions should still be investigated before resorting to `\resizebox`-- may be found at [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5001)

Comment: @Red-Cloud: Mabe you sould have a look at [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/486110/fit-longtable-to-textwidth#comment1229161_486110)  from 
David Carlisle, the developer of the `graphicx` package that adds the `\resizebox` command.

Comment: @leandriis: I know all that ...

Comment: May I suggest that you edit your answer to provide the needed context, and then we can delete this entire chain of comments?

Answer (score 7):

My main recommendation is that you switch from a `tabular` to a `tabular*` environment and set its width to `\textwidth`. Do also get rid of the 18 vertical rules: they do eat up quite a bit of space: moreover, they aren't needed. I'd also get rid of most horizontal rules.

Also, don't overuse **bold-facing**. Taking the time to provide a clear structure is a much better way to make the tabular material more accessible. As the following screenshot shows, I'd say that it's not necessary to use **bold-facing** at all. Do, though, consider aligning the numbers in each column on their respective decimal markers; this is done in the following example with the help of the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type.[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}
%\usepackage{graphicx,changepage}
%\newcommand{\var}{\textit}
%\newcommand{\proc}{\textbf}
%\newcommand{\prop}{\texttt}
%\newcommand{\plusplus}{{+}{+}}% Other options:
%\newcommand*\ita[1]{\textit{#1}}
%\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}% new
%\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{array,siunitx}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htb]
%%\centering % redundant
\caption{Precision/recall and completeness of the requirement-to-method traces output by our approach}
\label{Results}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
    lc 
    T{4.0} *{2}{T{6.0}} 
    *{3}{T{2.2}}
    T{3.0}T{5.0}*{2}{T{3.0}}T{6.0}
    *{4}{T{2.2}}}
    \toprule
    1- & 2- & {3-} & {4-} & {5-} & {6-} & {7-} & {8-} & {9-} & {10-} & 
    {11-} & {12-} & {13-} & {14-} & {15-} & {16-} & {17-} \\
    \addlinespace
    Program & Step 
    & \mc{3}{\mytab{Cumulative \\ Predictions}} 
    & \mc{3}{\mytab{Cumulative \\ Output\\ Completeness}}
    & \mc{5}{\mytab{Cumulative \\ Precision \\ and Recall}} 
    & \mc{2}{\mytab{Cumulative \\ Output \\ Precision}} 
    & \mc{2}{\mytab{Cumulative \\ Output \\ Recall}} \\
    \cmidrule{3-5} \cmidrule{6-8} \cmidrule{9-13}
    \cmidrule{14-15} \cmidrule{16-17}
    &
    & {T\textsubscript{p} (\#)} & {N\textsubscript{p} (\#)} & {E\textsubscript{p} (\#)}
    & {T (\%)} & {N (\%)} & {E (\%)}
    & {TP} & {TN} & {FP} & {FN} & {E}
    & {T (\%)} & {N (\%)}
    & {T (\%)} & {N (\%)} \\
    \midrule
    Chess & 1 & 0 & 2063 & 3953 & 0 & 34.29 & 65.71 & 0 & 1612 & 0 & 0 & 4404 & {NA} & 100 & {NA} & 100 \\    
    & 2 & 0 & 3227 & 2789 & 0 & 53.64 & 46.36 & 0 & 1841 & 0 & 49 & 4126 & {NA} & 97.41 & 0 & 100 \\    
    & 3 & 908 & 3227 & 1881 & 15.09 & 53.64 & 31.27 & 415 & 1841 & 378 & 49 & 3333 & 52.33 & 97.41 & 89.44 & 82.97 \\    
    & 4 & 1464 & 3227 & 1325 & 24.34 & 53.64 & 22.02 & 471 & 1841m& 438 & 49 & 3217 & 51.82 & 97.41 & 90.58 & 80.78 \\
    \addlinespace
    Gantt & 1 & 0 & 55535 & 34699 & 0 & 61.55 & 38.45 & 0 & 22365 & 0 & 0 & 67869 & {NA} & 100 & {NA} & 100 \\
    & 2 & 0 & 69880 & 20354 & 0 & 77.44 & 22.56 & 0 & 22707 & 0 & 94 & 67433 & {NA} & 99.59 & 0 & 100 \\    
    & 3 & 677 & 69880 & 19677 & 0.75 & 77.44 & 21.81 & 84 & 22707 & 85 & 94 & 67264 & 49.70 & 99.59 & 47.19 & 99.63 \\
    & 4 & 1143 & 69880 & 19211 & 1.27 & 77.44 & 21.29 & 136 & 22707 & 136 & 94 & 67161 & 50.00 & 99.59 & 59.13 & 99.40 \\
    \addlinespace
    iTrust & 1 & 0 & 17573 & 149265 & 0 & 10.53 & 89.47 & 0 & 6572 & 0 & 0 & 160266 & {NA} & 100 & {NA} & 100 \\
    & 2 & 0 & 28660 & 138178 & 0 & 17.18 & 82.82 & 0 & 6685 & 0 & 9 & 160144 & {NA} & 99.87 & 0 & 100 \\   
    & 3 & 290 & 28660 & 137888 & 0.17 & 17.18 & 82.65 & 81 & 6685 & 27 & 9 & 160036 & 75.00 & 99.87 & 90.00 & 99.60 \\    
    & 4 & 1074 & 28660 & 137104 & 0.64 & 17.18 & 82.18 & 93 & 6685 & 28 & 9 & 160023 & 76.86 & 99.87 & 91.18 & 99.58 \\
    \addlinespace
    JHotDraw & 1 & 0 & 116787 & 20133 & 0 & 85.30 & 14.70 & 0 & 12013 & 0 & 0 & 124907 & {NA} & 100 & {NA} & 100 \\
    & 2 & 0 & 128756 & 8164 & 0 & 94.04 & 5.96 & 0 & 12134 & 0 & 208 & 124578 & {NA} & 98.31 & 0 & 100 \\
    & 3 & 1279 & 128756 & 6885 & 0.93 & 94.04 & 5.03 & 63 & 12134 & 20 & 208 & 124495 & 75.90 & 98.31 & 23.25 & 99.84 \\
    & 4 & 2000 & 128756 & 6164 & 1.46 & 94.04 & 4.50 & 95 & 12134 & 32 & 208 & 124451 & 74.80 & 98.31 & 31.35 & 99.74 \\
    \addlinespace
    Average & 4 & 1420 & 57631 & 40951 & 6.93 & 60.57 & 32.50 & 199 & 10842 & 159 & 90 & 88713 & 63.37 & 98.79 & 68.06 & 94.88 \\
    \bottomrule

\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```