# Rotating page but not table and changing column setting for all columns

Tags: tables, lyx

I have a wide table (15 columns), I use `\begin{landscape}..\end{landscape}` to set the page to be landscape but it rotates my table  90 degree instead of setting landscape page. How should I rotate the page without rotating my table ?

Also, since I need to adjust column width to fit the page, is there a way for me to adjust column width for all columns on one go instead of clicking on each column to do adjustment 15 times ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Please provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) which reproduce your problem. Without seeing it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54304/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention i am using Lyx so I simply use insert - table function to create a  3 row * 15 column table. Where should I insert \begin{landscape}.\end{landscape} to rotate the page on which the table is and is there a way to set the setting for all the columns on one go ?